# Deploying rules with bolt adds extra "rules" wrapper

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, firebase-realtime-database

With a rules.bolt file that contains

```
path / {
  read() = true;
  write() = true;
}
```

and a firebase.json that contains

```
{...
  "rules": "rules.bolt"
}
```

running firebase deploy:rules results in the following rules:

```
{"rules":{"rules":{".read":"true",".write":"true"}}}
```

while it should be

```
{"rules":{".read":"true",".write":"true"}}
```

A current workaround is to run firebase-bolt locally and deploy the resulting json file.

Comment: What version of the CLI and Bolt do you have?

Comment: 2.1.0 and 0.5 respectively according to npm

Comment: I've got the same problem with the same versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this is fixed after version 2.1.0 of firebase-tools (not yet released as its own version).

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/pull/101